# 502 Bad Gateway when trying to point node.js app to nginx in production

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I'm trying to point my nodejs app to nginx so i can access the node.js app with my domain name, been trying for hours but nothing works, the name server are setup correctly, in fact i can access my nodejs app if i type in url the ip address of my server + the port

e.g.
192.168.1.1:3000

browser displays... **Hello world!**

but when i go to my domain name

e.g.
mydomainname.com

browser displays... **502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.18.0**

**server.js**

```
    ...

    //routes
    app.use("/", require("./routes/web"));
    app.use("/api", require("./routes/api"));

    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.status(404).send("Error 404");
    });

    const http = require('http');
    const hostname = '192.168.1.1';
    const port = 3000;
    const server = http.createServer(app);

    server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
      console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
    });

    ...
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/domainname.com**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name mydomainname.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.1:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
     }
}
```

for other folders and config files like sites-enabled/default is configure correctly and etc/nginx/nginx.conf is configured correctly since if i run
`sudo nginx -t` there's no error and the syntax is ok.

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Please Help, all tutorials and videos about this issue are way back from 2014-2018, there's nothing from 2019 or 2020

Comment: Are nginx and nodejs app running on different servers? Is 192.168.1.1 accessible from the server running nginx?

Comment: the node js is inside a droplet server in which i setup the nginx, they are running on the same server

Comment: it's weird becuase if i put e.g. http://mydomainname.com:3000 on my url bar the nodejs is accessible, however if i just access the domain without the port it's still showing 502 Bad Gateway

Comment: Maybe you should use `127.0.0.1` instead of `192.168.1.1`?

Comment: the ip address is just an example, and i've already tried 127.0.0.1:3000, localhost:3000, and the server's public_ip_address:3000 still not working it's still showing 502 Bad Gateway